# How to hide the upper part of a div with CSS

Tags: css, html, scroll

I need to create the illusion that an article's content is sliding underneath it's title when scrolling the page. The HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="header">
        <h1>Title</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="body">
        <p>a lot of content</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS looks like this at this point:

```
.wrapper{
  height: 100vh;
  width: 50%;
  margin-left: 25%;
  margin-top: 100px;
  position: relative;
}
.header{
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #fff;
  position: fixed;
  display: block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: calc(50% - 8px);
  z-index: 2;
}
.body{
  z-index: 1;
  top: 120px;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/joris508/frad472j/

Because there's an image in the background of the real website, I can't just put an element with a higher z-index to the top to hide that part.

I also tried to make the content portion (.body) scrollable itself. That created the right effect visually, but because the background-image on the page has a parallax scroll effect, scrolling the div itself caused problems.

Is there any solution to this problem?